# WebDriverException - unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

O.S ->
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 21.1
Release:    21.1
Codename:   vera

Getting below response when i run my TestNG file.

Response ->
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'sushant-Vostro-15-3568', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-56-generic', java.version: '17.0.5'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

How to resolve this binary chrome issue?

Comment: You should include your driver initialization code.  Also make sure Chrome is installed on that machine.